# is there a method that helps me to Like Facebook pages using python selenium

Tags: python

i am writing a code on python by using selenium that login into Facebook and Like a Facebook page i requested. it works to login but after opening the Facebook page i requested, it wont like the page.any help would be appreciated

[image: First it go to my Facebook account ,Then it find the page i requested after that it goes to a specific post found on that page and like the post]

Comment: Given the information you've included in this question, what would you need to be able to even start answering it?

Comment: Maybe if you add some code ?

Comment: What i need is the code that goes to a specific Page and like the Page. you can see the code it in the link

Comment: Raphael , i added some code but i am unable to get what i really wanted

Comment: @Sayse you can see what i faced while running the script in the link above

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you logged in to the Facebook you need find the DOM(document object model) or element. Each button each link in the Facebook consist of their own Dom properties. For an example consider you see a button in a website just press f12 to see the button property that button might contain a id,class,or tag field. You need to find the id or tag and then you need to pass that element into your code.

id = "one"

In your python script,

The selenium library has one attribute called find_element_by_id.
Just pass the id into the attribute find_element_by_id("one").click()

That's it.

Comment: I used the attribute find_element_by_xpath( "UFILikeLink").click()......but still does not click the like button

Comment: Try using find_element_by_id, class, name or tag. Add click function in the same line.